# Not able to export a xlsx file in ie9 using angular 9

Tags: angular9

**Not able to export a xlsx file in IE9 in angular 9**
Below is the code :

```
exportexcel(): void {
    /* table id is passed over here */
    let element = document.getElementById('excel-table');
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(element);

    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

exportexcel(): void {
    let element = document.getElementById('excel-table');
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(element);

    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    const blob: Blob = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8' });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'Data.xlsx'));
}
```

Comment: It is working fine with IE11,10. But for IE9 I am getting below error in the console :"ERROR ReferenceError: 'Blob' is undefined"